# Resize plot created with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerpoint

I'm creating plot with R for a power point. I have to create picture with size 
 width = 4.24 inch, height = 2.55 inch . So I create my plot:

```
graf<-ggplot(...)
```

Then I save It

```
win.metafile (file, width = 4.24, height = 2.55)
plot(graf)
dev.off()
```

This is the result[image]

My problem is that the plot is too mutch "in the center" of the shape. I'd like to shift it near the bottom. I'd like to keep the legend more near the bottom and more near the plot. I expect that doing so and keeping the height fixed, the bar plots will be more thin and tall( I have fixed the scale y to be "8"). I'd like also reduce the white border in the left and in the right. Somebody know the correct way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried playing with various settings in `theme()` that can be used to adjust plot margins, legend position, etc?

Comment: I used `plot.margin =unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "lines")` and helps a little, but still I have too mutch margins.

Comment: You can also input negative values

Comment: Oh thank you! Now I solved the problem in the right and in the left. What remains is the distance betwen the legend and the x axis.

Comment: You can use `theme(legend.position = ...)`. If you set it equal to a numeric vector of length 2 (rather than a string like "top", "bottom" etc), you can adjust it so it is where you want. Check out also the `legend.justification` and `legend.direction` options.

Comment: Now I set `plot.margin =  unit(c(-0.1,-0.1, 2,0), "lines")`. The bottom is "2" so I can put the leged. Then I put `theme(legend.position = c(0.5,-0.1))`. The position is correct and also the margins, but the legend is vertical! So to adjust I set: `legend.direction='horizantal'` But this give me an error:`Error in if (!g$title.position %in% c("top", "bottom", "left", "right")) stop("title position \"",  : 
  argument is of length zero`

Comment: The word is "horizontal" and not "horizantal", so you need `legend.direction='horizontal'`. Please have a good look at `?theme` and http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/. It will help you resolve these problems much faster on your own.

Answer (score 0):

you can save your ggplots by a function

```
ggsave(plot,filename,width,height.....)
```

I think decreasing the width should solve your problem. If it doesn't then you can use the

```
graf<-ggplot(...)
graf <- graf+theme(legend.position = c(x,y))
```

arguments to place the legend exactly where do you want it to be.

Comment: If I do `theme(legend.position = c(x,y))` then the leggend will not be anymore horizzontal and the space for the legend disappear

Comment: for that you can set legend.direction='horizantal'

Comment: It returns `Error in if (!g$title.position %in% c("top", "bottom", "left", "right")) stop("title position \"", : argument is of length zero`